# Can someone estimate the limit of this function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{|x+1|-|x-1|}{x}$$ and also sketch a graph. This has been bothering me for a day now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: You could start by drawing a graph of the function $f(x) = |x + 1| - |x-1|$. The limit above will be the derivative of $f$ at $x = 0$, if it exists. It should then hopefully be clear how to algebraically derive that result.

Comment: @user270997 It's not very helpful to ask whether somebody can do this since you can be sure someone can... it would be better (for you) if you tell some of your own efforts - even if you think they are not right...

Answer (score 8):

The limit is trivial: as $x \to 0$, we have that $x+1>0$ and $x-1<0$, hence
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+1-(1-x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}{x}=2.
$$
Here is a [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e83i90npvle).

[image: Graph of function, it's 2/|x| outside [-1,1] and 2 between -1 and 1]

Comment: I'm not quite convinced answering a question where the OP states "this has been bothering [her/him] for a day now" by "this is trivial" is the best way to encourage people.

Comment: @ClementC. I do not want to encourage anyone, actually...

Comment: Oh. In that case, I reckon it's just fine.

Comment: You know... :-)

Comment: The only thing I have to complain about is that the OP did not write down any own ideas although he says he had tried a day.

Comment: @Rhjg: The OP said nothing about having tried all day - only about having been bothered by it ;-) How are you supposed to fill in further relevant details about such state of mind?

Comment: @String Hm, okay, you are right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another funny way to do this is using the old trick for simplifying expressions involving square roots:
$$\frac{|x+1|-|x-1|}{x}=\frac{(|x+1|-|x-1|)(|x+1|+|x-1|)}{x(|x+1|+|x-1|)}=\frac{(x+1)^2-(x-1)^2}{x(|x+1|+|x-1|)}=\frac{4}{|x+1|+|x-1|}$$
And now it is clear that, as $x$ approaches 0 the denominator approaches 2 and hence the limit is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{|x+1|-|x-1|}{x}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{|x+1|+|x-1|}{|x+1|+|x-1|}\right)$$

Now Using the formula $\displaystyle x^2 = |x|^2\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

So we get $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left[(x+1)^2-(x-1)^2\right]}{x\cdot \left(|x+1|+|x-1|\right)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4x}{x\cdot \left(|x+1|+|x-1|\right)} = 2$$

Answer (score 0):

When calculating a limit you only have worry about the function in intervals as small as you'd like.

In this case we can work with $x\in(-1,1)$.

When $x\neq 0$ is in this interval we have  $|x+1|=x+1$ and $|x-1|=1-x$. So $f(x)=\frac{x+1-(1-x)}{x}=\frac{2x}{x}=2$.

So if we take $\delta\leq1$ then whenever $0<|x|<\delta$ we have $f(x)=2$. So $|f(x)-2|=0<\epsilon$. So for every epsilon greater than zero we can give a $\delta$. In fact $\delta=1$ works for every epsilon, which is not something we see every day, in any case this proves the limit is $2$.

Comment: Why do you not work with $x\in (-1,1)$?

Comment: I didn't give it much thought, but $(-1,1)$ does the trick also. Thanks for noticing.